# Embed Flash player inside Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, google-chrome-app

Developing Chrome Apps is a major pain in the ass because of all the restrictions. I've been trying to find some sort of way to embed a flash object inside it and I just can't do it.

Basically, it's an external flash object that you embed using inline javascript. And no I can't download the object or anything like that, because it receives data from the server.

If it matters this is what I'm trying to embed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var zippywww="50";var zippyfile="30734813";var zippytext="#000000";var zippyback="#e8e8e8";var zippyplay="#232323";var zippywidth=850;var zippyauto=false;var zippyvol=80;var zippywave = "#000000";var zippyborder = "#cccccc";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js"></script>
```

And no I can't use anything else, because the player needs to play files from that host.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is listed as a disabled web feature on the Chrome App developer site: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated. The suggestion is to use HTML5 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that HTML into a webview. (Haven't tried it myself, but it might work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Flash plugin as "always allowed to run" in the Chrome settings and it seems to work well in my packaged app. The feature is supposed to be deprecated so I can make no guarantee about it, but it does work in practice for now.